# Check array contains element at compile time

Tags: c++, constant-expression

We have a `modifyCoefficient(const char* name, int value)` function that updates the value of a coefficient in a container. The names are known at compile time, they are read from an XML file in a pre-build step and stored in an array.
Usage: `data.modifyCoefficient("ADAPTIVE", 1);`
Compiler: MSVC 2017 v15.8

I would like to get a compile time error when the coefficient name does not exist.
With the following code that happens, but is there a way to do it without a macro?

```
#include <array>

#define COEFF(name) returnName<coefficientExists(name)>(name)

constexpr std::array<const char*, 3> COEFFICIENTS = { "VERSION", "CHANNELS", "ADAPTIVE" };

constexpr bool coefficientExists(const char* name)
{
    for (auto coefficientIndex = 0U; coefficientIndex < COEFFICIENTS.size(); ++coefficientIndex)
    {
        if (COEFFICIENTS[coefficientIndex] == name)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<bool CoefficientTest>
constexpr const char* returnName(const char* name)
{
    static_assert(CoefficientTest, "coefficient does not exist");
    return name;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(coefficientExists("VERSION"), "should exist");
    static_assert(coefficientExists("TEST") == false, "should not exist");
    static_assert(COEFF("ADAPTIVE") == "ADAPTIVE", "should return name");
    COEFF("CHANNELS");
    // data.modifyCoefficient(COEFF("ADAPTIVE"), 1);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/kpGcMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++20's `consteval` this is now possible without `static_assert` or macro's.
Solution based on [C++20 to eliminate runtime bugs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/how-we-used-cpp20-to-eliminate-an-entire-class-of-runtime-bugs/) and [Compile-time format string checks](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2022).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

constexpr auto COEFFICIENTS = std::array{ "VERSION"sv, "CHANNELS"sv, "POWER"sv };

struct CoefficientName
{
   std::string_view str;

    consteval CoefficientName(std::string_view name)
        :str(name)
    {
        if(std::ranges::find(COEFFICIENTS, name) == COEFFICIENTS.end())
            throw;
    }
};

void modifyCoefficient(CoefficientName name, int value)
{
}

int main()
{
    modifyCoefficient("CHANNELS"sv, 42);
    modifyCoefficient("CURRENT"sv, 99); // compilation error
    modifyCoefficient("POWER"sv, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M3oE4acxc

Answer (score 4):

You have to compare values char by char, or even simpler change `const char*` to `std::string_view` make your code work.

Thanks to the deduction guides, you can just write `std::array = ...` and template parameters will be automatically deduced.

Also, you can simplify your loop using a "range-based `for`".
 If we generalize for other types of compile-time array, we get:

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;
constexpr std::array COEFFICIENTS = { "VERSION"sv, "CHANNELS"sv, "ADAPTIVE"sv };

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr bool array_has(const std::array<T, N>& array, const T& value) {
  for (const auto& v : array) {
    if (value == v) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

constexpr bool coefficientExists(const std::string_view name)
{
    return array_has(COEFFICIENTS, name);
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(coefficientExists("VERSION"), "should exist");
    static_assert(!coefficientExists("TEST"), "should not exist");
}
```

With C++20 you can even do simpler:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr bool array_has(const std::array<T, N> array, const T value) {
return std::any_of(array.begin(), array.end(), [value](auto current){ return current == value; });
}
```

Comment: Should `array_has` take its arguments by const *reference*, rather than const *value*?  I'd be inclined to make `v` a const ref, too.  You could argue that it's unnecessary, but it could help performance when called with non-`constexpr` arguments.

Comment: Constexpr range-based for with std::array and std::string_view don't seem to be supported by MSVC 2017 v15.8.

The problem with `coefficientExists("VERSION")` is that it is not automatically evaluated at compile time. It's only being evaluated at compile time because of the `static_assert`, that's why I had to use the macro.